# D11 42131 caterpillar

Tags: control-plus

I have stared to build the above and I was half way through  point of inserting the connectors to the hub. I have tried all the ports and looking at the schematic plan on on page 169 and have followed the instructions to the letter the diagram and I can only get the blue connections to work in the hub. I have been trying to figure it out for 4 days now

[image]

Comment: Apologies with bad explanation above I should of said the only connectors  i have working is blue and green but cannot get the red and yellow connectors to show yellow and red as per the schematic plan above

Comment: You mean you expect hub make LED's light up in these exact colors? Based on this diagram, colors are used here to help you align each motor with correct location in hub. Are you running a test within the mobile app and it fails?

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for reaching out for me, I will take a couple of snap shots which may be easier than me explaining this issue if that’s ok with yourself

Comment: Hi Alex I look on my controller app  I have green and blue , ticked but I cannot seem to get yellow  and red ticked as it shows two crosses

Comment: Am I doing something fundamentally wrong ?

Comment: There have been quite a few questions with regards to 42131 set and LEGO Control+ app. Not sure how many of us here own this particular set to verify the issue. I would suspect the issue is with mobile app, but don't have anything to prove the statement.

Comment: Hi Alex is there a way I can send you a screen shot showing the issue i am facing at the moment, I am not sure if could forward this on to you

Comment: I have no means of helping with this particular issue, unfortunately. However, you can also try reaching out to LEGO Customer Service to address your issue. If it happens you find the solution this way please make sure to return here and post your solution as an answer to this question.

Comment: Hi Alex I contacted Lego regarding the issue was facing and they gave me some trouble shooting options but when I tried to copy these to send to you I cannot add the comments due to how much I can send to you because I have used more characters

Comment: If the troubleshooting suggested by LEGO Customer Service proved to be helpful you can post these details not as comment, but as an answer in a field below "comments" section.